# Using folium.Map and getting Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported

Tags: python, python-3.x, maps, folium

I am trying to run this function.

```
def create_map(cust,hotel):
    m = folium.Map(location=[cust.Latitude.mean(), cust.Longitude.mean()], zoom_start=12, tiles='OpenStreetMap')
    for _, row in cust.iterrows():
         
        if row['Condition']=='Out':
            cluster_colour='blue'
        else:
            cluster_colour = 'green'
        
        folium.CircleMarker(
            location= [row['Latitude'],row['Longitude']],
            radius=5,
            popup= row[['Condition','Place_Name']],
            color=cluster_colour,
            fill=True,
            fill_color=cluster_colour
            ).add_to(m)
    
    for _, row in hotel.iterrows(): 
        folium.Marker(
            location= [row['Latitude'],row['Longitude']],
            radius=5,
            popup= row['Hotel'],
            color='red',
            fill=True,
            fill_color='red'
             ).add_to(m)
    for _, row in hotel.iterrows(): 
        folium.Circle(
            location= [row['Latitude'],row['Longitude']],
            radius=3000,
            popup= row['Hotel'],
            color='black',
            fill=False,
        ).add_to(m)
        
    return m
```

I keep getting this error.

```
KeyError: 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike'
```

I am calling the function like this.

```
m = create_map(cust_loc,hotel_loc)
m
```

The cust_loc dataframe and hotel_loc have 'Latitude' and 'Longitude' field names.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like folium/pandas don't support lists being used, try converting the lists to numpy arrays who work with those.

for example:

```
list = list.to_numpy()
```